# I want to throw out an input dialog to input a number in Google Chrome to go to a specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

When a specific bookmark on Chrome is clicked on, I want to throw out an input dialog to input a number. The number entered would be stored as a variable somewhere and then replace the "#" in the default link to "http://emoji.tapatalk-cdn.com/emoji#.png" or **any** URL in which the images are in numerical order. This would then go to the specific URL with the image number entered. I believe that a JavaScript script / JQuery can be used but I am unsure as to how to do it.

**Example:**

1. I would open up Chrome and click on the specific bookmark, in my example: the one titled "Emoji#.png".
2. The dialog would throw out the following message: "Which image number do you wish to go to? Enter a valid integer number based on the specific website."
3. I would then input a number, e.g. 23, and press the enter key OR click on the okay button on the Chrome dialog.
4. The script would then replace the "#" / the default value with the inputted number, i.e. 23, and then send me to the link it created. e.g. http://emoji.tapatalk-cdn.com/emoji23.png

Comment: SO can not help you in writing an algo or an app. Your questions should be around what you tried, what didn't work or how to fix this. Please share what you learned and what you have tried already.

Comment: This looks like something that would be easy to do with a simple javascript bookmarklet.

Comment: Okay Jehanzeb.Malik you're right in what you're saying but I am a Java programmer (pre-university). Looking to expand my programming language knowledge but right now I just need a solution to this question as   I want to speed up access time. This is not going to be used commercially, etc. Strictly for personal use and to help others decrease access time. Thank you.

Comment: @KeeganNaidoo still you need to show us your effort in this first. It does not have to do anything with commercial product. You will see tons of questions related to these big products you see online. But all those questions mention what they tried. And that is what we ask you. Show us what you found out, tell us what you tried and/or already have.